# Resolve "Invalid dropzone element" error: inserting script tag the wrong way

Tags: javascript, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am getting the following error:

***Invalid dropzone element***

The two files of interest are the following:

*layouts/app.blade.php*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Presto.it') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@6.0.0-beta.1/dist/dropzone-min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/dropzone@6.0.0-beta.1/dist/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        @include('layouts._nav')

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    new Dropzone("#image-upload", {
        thumbnailWidth:200,
        maxFilesize:1,
        acceptedFiles:".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif"
    });
</script>
</html>
```

*new.blade.php*

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form action="{{ route('announcement.create') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="uniqueSecret" value="{{ $uniqueSecret }}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Categoria</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select name="category" id="category">
                                    @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                    <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ old('category') == $category->id ? 'selected' : ''}}>{{ $category->name }}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('category')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <h3>Dropzone</h3>
                        <form action="{{route('dropzone.store')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="image-upload" class="dropzone">
                            @csrf

                        </form>

                        <button type="submit">Add</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

From what I'm understanding, I hope I'm not wrong, the problem is the script tag present in layouts.

As you can see in the code there is a form (useful for creating the ad) with the Dropzone form (useful for uploading images)

Can anyone kindly help me?

Comment: I see no issue if the element with the id 'image-upload' actually exists. It works here: https://jsfiddle.net/6fcexq5a/

Comment: @Unmitigated I think it's more the incorrect way I declare the script tag. This is Laravel

Comment: I just noticed the placement of the `<script>`. You should not put it after the `<body>`; instead, place it before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: @Unmitigated I always get the error

Comment: Are you sure there's actually an element with the id `'image-upload'` on the page? Check the console.

Comment: @Unmitigated could it be the form inside another form? See code for clarification